# SAS How to concatenate strings several times in the same variable during a data step

Tags: sas, datastep

A very basic question.

How come I cannot change a variable in a datastep like this?

```
data want;
   aaaaa='[';
   aaaaa=cats(aaaaa,'hello');
   aaaaa=cats(aaaaa,']');
   put aaaaa;
run;
```

> aaaaa will be equal to '[' , I expect '[hello]'

I need to define `aaaaa` in multiple steps because I need to construct `aaaaa` with do loops (with unpredictable length), I can't define `aaaaa` in just one step.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to do put for aaaaa variable? the value for aaaaa in table want equals [hello].

Comment: @andrey_sz Yes I do. It's for building a json file.

Comment: Also look into `call cats` as it saves you having to specifiy `aaaaa = cats(aaaaa, ......)`

Comment: @Keith `aaaaa=cats(aaaaa,'bbbbb');` would be equivalent to `call cats(aaaaa,aaaaa,'bbbbb');`?  I don't see what's the advantage of that. It's even longer.

Comment: @ooo no, it's just `call cats(aaaaa,'bbbbb');`

Comment: @ooo I'll add an example as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When first calling aaaaa SAS will assign a length to the variable. In this case `length aaaaa $1` as you only assign one character. SAS data types are not dynamic. Start your datastep by assigning your variable a fixed length that covers the maximal expected length e.g.

```
data want;
    length aaaaa $300;
    aaaaa='[';
    aaaaa=cats(aaaaa,'hello');
    aaaaa=cats(aaaaa,']');
    put aaaaa;
run;
```

Comment: I was pretty sure it was something stupid I missed :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add `attrib` or `format` statement to data-step:

```
data want;
   attrib 
      aaaaa format=$200.;
   aaaaa='[';
   aaaaa=cats(aaaaa,'hello');
   aaaaa=cats(aaaaa,']');
   put aaaaa;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments, here's an alternative way using `call cats`.

```
data want;
length aaaaa $300;
call cats(aaaaa,'[');
call cats(aaaaa,'Hello');
call cats(aaaaa,']');
run;
```